# calling a stored procedure in the initialization of a variable

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I am trying to call another stored procedure to get the returned value and assign it to the variable declared in my sql stored procedure but i get an error:

> Msg 4121, Level 16, State 1, Procedure proc_GetChemicalDaily, Line 35
>   Cannot find either column "Interface" or the user-defined function or aggregate "Interface.proc_GetPIValueAverageTime", or the name is ambiguous.

I have tried to replace the SELECT in front with an 'EXECUTE' and 'EXEC' and i also had to tag something at the end but it didn't work. i also placed the database name in front of the "Interface" part.

```
USE [OperationsView]
GO
/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [Interface].[proc_GetChemicalDaily]
Script Date: 1/27/2017 8:06:47 AM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
-- =============================================
-- Author:      <Author,,Name>
 -- Create date: <Create Date,,>
 -- Description:    <Description,,>
 -- =============================================
 ALTER PROCEDURE [Interface].[proc_GetChemicalDaily]
-- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here

@ProductionDate As DateTime,
@Debug BIT = 1

 AS
 BEGIN
-- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
-- interfering with SELECT statements.
SET NOCOUNT ON;

-- pi variables
DECLARE @tag_in As varchar(50)
DECLARE @pi_server As varchar(50)
DECLARE @enddate As date
--forcast variables
DECLARE @FCChemGALPERMIN DECIMAL(18,4)
DECLARE @CAUSTICDAILYUSAGE DECIMAL(18,4)

--variance variables
--DECLARE @PriceVariance DECIMAL(18,4)

   -- DECLARE @MTDChem$Ton DECIMAL(18,4)
  SELECT @tag_in = 'I-FC-835'
  SELECT @pi_server = 'valpi'
  SELECT @endDate = DATEADD(DAY, 1, @productionDate)
  SELECT @FCChemGALPERMIN = proc_GetPIValueAverageTime(@tag_in, 
  @ProductionDate, @endDate, @pi_server, @Debug)

    if @FCChemGALPERMIN> .5
     SELECT @CAUSTICDAILYUSAGE = @FCChemGALPERMIN*((18318/2000)*.5);
    else
     SELECT @CAUSTICDAILYUSAGE = 0;


-- Insert statements for procedure here
   if @Debug = 1
begin
    PRINT '-------------COST OF CAUSTIC-------------'
    PRINT''
    PRINT 'Caustic for production day ' + convert(varchar(50),@ProductionDate) 
    PRINT ''
    PRINT 'Caustic usage: ' + convert(varchar(50),@CAUSTICDAILYUSAGE) 
end
  END
```

Comment: Lose the parentheses and try: `EXEC @FCChemGALPERMIN = proc_GetPIValueAverageTime @tag_in, 
  @ProductionDate, @endDate, @pi_server, @Debug`

Comment: Also, you may want to qualify the proc with `Interface.`

Comment: How does proc_GetPIValueAverageTime return a value (select statement, return statement, output parameter?) You may not get the results you expect from it calling it like that.

Comment: The RETURN_VALUE is an int and is intended to return a value indicating the status of the execution. It is NOT intended to return a  user defined value. If you want data returned from a stored procedure you should use an OUTPUT parameter.

Comment: GREAT! thanks i used EXEC instead on SELECT and used OUTPUT and got rid of parenthesis. thanks